# How to split a string character by character, , paying attention to special characters

Tags: php, string, split

I'm trying to explode a string character by character but I've a trouble with special characters.
I'm currently using the following function:

```
<?php
$input = "Comment ça va?";
$array_input = str_split($input, 1);
print_r($array_input);
?>
```

Here's the output:

```
Array (
[0] => C [1] => o [2] => m [3] => m [4] => e
[5] => n [6] => t [7] => [8] => � [9] => �
[10] => a [11] => [12] => v [13] => a [14] => ? )
```

I've the same issue with the line break:

Input:
"Hé!
Oui?"

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => H [1] => � [2] => � [3] => ! [4] => 
[5] => [6] => O [7] => u [8] => i [9] => ? )
```

Does anybody have a solution for this issue?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str_split` has problems with Unicode strings.

You can use the `u` modifier in `preg_split` instead

For instance:

```
$input = "Comment ça va?";
$letters1 = str_split($input);
$letters2 = preg_split('//u', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($letters1);
print_r($letters2);
```

Will output

```
Array ( [0] => C [1] => o [2] => m [3] => m [4] => e 
        [5] => n [6] => t [7] => [8] => � [9] => � 
        [10] => a [11] => [12] => v [13] => a [14] => ? ) 

Array ( [0] => C [1] => o [2] => m [3] => m [4] => e 
        [5] => n [6] => t [7] => [8] => ç [9] => a 
        [10] => [11] => v [12] => a [13] => ? )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works with special characters but not for line breaks:  
INPUT: hé!  
oui?  

OUTPUT:  
    Array ( [0] => h [1] => é [2] => ! [3] => [4] => [5] => o [6] => u [7] => i [8] => ?)

Comment: @Zorkzyd: It is actually working: positions 3 and 4 are respectively \r and \n... (Try `ord($letters[3])` and `ord($letters[4])` and you will get 13 and 10 respectively, which are the ASCII codes of `\r` and `\n`).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is it possible to "merge" the \r\n in the output's array?

Comment: @Zorkzyd: you could remove them from the string before calling `preg_split`. For instance: `$input = preg_replace('/\\r\\n/', '', $input);`

Comment: I should have know it :)
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This is because PHP's `str_split` function is not multibyte-safe, i.e. it can't handle Unicode correctly. You can use this function instead, which is a multibyte-safe implementation of `str_split`

```
function mb_str_split( $string ) { 
    # Split at all position not after the start: ^ 
    # and not before the end: $ 
    return preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $string ); 
}
```

(source: user comments in [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php#99851))